# Are words such as "today" and "yesterday" introductory words or adverbial phrases?

Tags: commas, adverbial-phrases

When I first started learning about punctuation, I found out that you should always have commas after words such as "*today*," "*sometimes*," "*yesterday,*" and so on. Today, I found a [website that disagrees](http://victoryediting.com/introductory-words-such-as-now-today-etc/), it says:

> If you have an introductory word (or two) that is being used as an adverb (usually answers the question of when, where, why, or to what degree), then no comma. If it’s being used as a conjunction, then go ahead and use a comma.
>
> For example:
>   **“Someday, I’d like to go on a cruise.”** — This is *incorrect*. Someday is functioning as an adverbial phrase, answering the question of WHEN I would like to go on a cruise. Correct would be this:
>   **“Someday I’d like to go on a cruise.”**

I want to know how legitimate this website actually is. Can someone verify this for me?

Comment: These are _recommendations,_ not rules. The website is legitimate. Other websites with different recommendations are "legitimate", too. Where did you learn that one should "always have commas after words such as 'today,' 'sometimes,'" etc.? That is just false. "Yesterday I dined at 8." "Today I arose at 7." Tim, you are looking for rules where none exist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48110/discussion-on-question-by-tim-are-words-such-as-today-and-yesterday-introduc).

Answer (score 1):

As in many languages, in English, commas represent the pauses that a speaker would include when saying the sentence out loud.  In this way it mirrors the natural *rhythm* of the language, which varies considerably between different dialects and different individuals.

So most rules that seem to *require* commas before or after certain words or phrases are simply guidelines to help you organize your English sentences. It's a good idea to *learn* these guidelines, and understand what purpose they serve, but then pay attention to how native speakers talk and write, and develop your own personal style.

That being said: words like "tomorrow" and "yesterday" may be followed by a comma if you wish to help separate it from the next word or phrase in the sentence.  Sometimes this helps understand the sentence better:

> Someday, you and I will go on a cruise.
>
> Someday you and I will on a cruise.

The comma helps separate the ending "y" of "someday" and the starting "y" of "you" in the same way that a speaker might insert a pause there.  The comma is not necessary, and it does not change the *meaning* of the sentence, but it does change the *rhythm* of the sentence to mimic natural speech patterns.

Comment: I always am a little wary when we tell learners that commas are for pauses. I've read plenty of credible bloggers who cite that as a "common myth." I won't delve into it here, but I did give some examples at [this answer to a related ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96807/can-the-comma-be-used-to-create-a-pause-in-a-long-sentence/100961#100961).

Answer (score -1):

## No, basically never

> Today I ate the nugget.

Well, no comma I guess.

They give very good examples like

> Tomorrow I’m going to get my hair done.
>
> Yesterday I paid the car note.
>
> Next week is finals week.

I guess not being fluent in English is different, but it gives an explanation

> If you have an introductory word (or two) that is being used as an adverb (usually answers the question of when, where, why, or to what degree), then no comma.

An adverb modifies a verb, adjective, or adverb. Like in the quote, it says when, where, why, or to what degree.